# Splitting a Single Column to Multiple sub-columns/arrays in Python

Tags: python, decision-tree, cross-validation, supervised-learning, train-test-split

I'm trying to implement a decision tree algorithm in Python to predict missing input data.

Say I have a column with 99 entries. Out of this 99 entries, 20 are NaN. I want to break up this single array into x numbers of size y (y = 5 in this case) sub-arrays.

The sub-arrays with complete cells are assigned to **features** and the ones that contain **NaN** are assigned to **target**.

```
 # breaking target array into subarrays
subarray_size = 5
target = []
features = []

# complete break up and assign to array "chunks"
chunks = [test[x : x + subarray_size] for x in xrange(0, len(test), subarray_size)]

# assigns NaN containg subarray to "target" and filled subarrays to "features"
for i in chunks:
    if (np.where(np.isnan(i)))[0].shape[0]: 
        target.append(i)
    else:
        features.append(i)
```

Code works all the way till the end of for loop. Now that I have **features** and **target**, I tried the below code block

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split as tts

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = tts(features, target, test_size=0.2)
```

which yielded this error:

```
    202     if len(uniques) > 1:
    203         raise ValueError("Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of"
--> 204                          " samples: %r" % [int(l) for l in lengths])
    205 
    206 

ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [5, 15].
```

I think the error occurred somewhere during the array operations. I'm having trouble fixing it. Any advice/insights/suggestions?

**EDIT**: below is the sample "test" column. Not sure how to put it in table format. Sorry about the bad visuals.

```
Site2_ThirdIonizationEnergy

39.722
39.722
33.667
39.722
39.722
23.32
25.04
NaN
27.491
22.99
39.722
23.32
25.04
NaN
27.491
22.99
33.667
23.32
33.667
NaN
27.491
22.99
39.722
23.32
25.04
NaN
27.491
22.99
19.174
19.174
19.174
19.174
39.722
39.722
33.667
39.722
39.722
23.32
25.04
NaN
27.491
22.99
39.722
23.32
25.04
NaN
27.491
22.99
33.667
23.32
33.667
NaN
27.491
22.99
39.722
23.32
25.04
NaN
27.491
22.99
39.722
39.722
33.667
39.722
39.722
39.722
33.667
39.722
39.722
23.32
25.04
NaN
27.491
22.99
39.722
23.32
25.04
NaN
27.491
22.99
33.667
23.32
33.667
NaN
27.491
22.99
39.722
23.32
25.04
NaN
27.491
22.99
21.62
21.62
21.62
21.62
39.722
39.722
33.667
```

Comment: Can you include example data from 'test'?

Comment: added the test column. @Metropolis

Answer (score 1):

Well, looking at `test` and the way you create `features` and `target` it's pretty clear that the number of features and the number of targets are different. I think you may be confused about the meaning of those two objects.

For a given record, you'll have both a set of features describing that record and a single target, representing which class you know that record to be in. So if you are trying to predict who will survive the Titanic, your features might be things like: the boarding class, the person's age, the person's gender and the target would be weather or not they survived.

For each person, you need both their features and their target. Your classifier will then train on the features and the targets to learn what patterns in the features are associate to which targets. Then, later on, when you see a new example where you know the features but not the target, the `predict` method will take the patterns learned and return its best guess of what the target probably is (or rather, the probability for each possible value of the target).

The target isn't the data you're trying to fill in. It's the KNOWN result for example cases that you would use to teach the algorithm how to guess at unknown values. In the training phase you have to tell the algorithm what the answer should be.

What you're trying to do is not a classification problem, but rather you're trying to "impute missing values." This requires a different approach entirely from the one you're attempting.

If your data is a timeseries (that is, each value is taken from a point in time for some measurement) then you may consider using a moving average (ARMA or ARIMA) or "exponential smoothing" to impute the missing values.

Though, depending on your purposes, you might also just be able to take the mean of the surrounding values, or the median of several surrounding values.